# OTP Pins Are Different on OTP.NET and OTPTest WebSite

Tags: c#, .net, one-time-password, totp

I'm currently testing an OTP scenario using the website https://otptest.de/ and the OTP.NET library. However, I'm consistently getting different OTP PINs between my code and the website. I have provided my code in the following gist: [text](https://gist.github.com/emreozguruoglu/0222e51bc56330912afd52c7c3f5cc86)

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this discrepancy and ensure that the OTP PIN generated by my code matches the one generated by the otptest.de website.

Tried otp scenario. Didn't generate same one with the website.

Comment: OTP.NET works, as long as you use the *correct* key. That key may or may not be BASE32-encoded. Post minimal code that reproduces the problem in the question itself, not in a link to a gist that may disappear in 15 minutes. Post the `new Totp(...)` and `totp.ComputeTotp();` calls, what you expected and what you got

Comment: Please don't post links to your code. Instead, include the actual code in this question.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos thanks resolve issue. I use Base32Encoding.ToBytes and resolved. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this myself. The "secret" provided by most OTP generators is BASE32-encoded. OTP.NET expects the decoded bytes as a secret.

The following code produces the same token as the test site. It uses the `Base32Encoding` helper class to decode the secret into the actual bytes:

```
var base32Bytes = Base32Encoding.ToBytes("MYM5VAQ");
var otp = new Totp(base32Bytes);
    
var token=otp.ComputeTotp();
```

Comment: Many thanks. Normally I used on problem Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes, I think that's why my code not worked.

Comment: `.ASCII.GetBytes` guarantees lost data. It refers to the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage that can't even handle all English words, like `naïve`. In the case of randomly generated keys the chance of mangling a byte is 50% (all values above 0x7F)